# Class or type name not found - type Object

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am a beginner in LotusScript, I have the following error in my agent:

[image: Class or type name not found]

My goal is to be able to connect to the server with the following code:

```
Option Public
Option Declare    

Sub Initialize
    Dim myServer As String
    Dim myMailfile As String
    myServer = "server"
    myMailfile = "mailfile"

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim intErgebnis As Integer
    Dim objNotes As Object
    Dim LNdb As Object
    Dim LNView As Object
    Dim LNDoc As Object
    Dim LNItem As Object
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim LNWorkspace As Object
    Dim LNAttachment As Variant
    intErgebnis = 0
    Set objNotes = GetObject("", "Notes.NotesSession")
    Set LNdb = objNotes.GETDATABASE(myServer, myMailfile)
    Set LNWorkspace = CreateObject("notes.notesuiworkspace")
    LNWorkspace.OpenDatabase myServer, myMailfile
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no data type called Object in Lotusscript.
You need to declare those variables with their proper object types, e.g. NotesDatabase, NotesView, NotesDocument, etc.

Also, you should declare and initialize a NotesSession object, not use GetObject() in Lotusscript.  It looks like you are trying to write COM code, not Lotusscript.

Another suggestion is to use variable names that are conforming to the de-facto (established) naming convention. If you look at other Lotusscript code, you will notice that the variables generally are named the same way, making it much easier to read other developer's code. Yet another recommendation is to declare all Notes objects/classes first, grouped/sorted in the order they are being used, followed by the rest of the variables, before any of them are assigned values.

Your code should look more like this:

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim item As NotesItem
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument

    Dim mailServer As String
    Dim mailFileName As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim resultCount As Integer
    Dim subject As String

    mailServer = "server"
    mailFileName = "mailfile.nsf"
    resultCount = 0
    ' *** Open the specified mail file using back-end classes
    Set db = new NotesDatabase(mailServer, mailFileName)
    ' *** Get the document currently open in the Notes client using front-end classes
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    
End Sub
```

You see how much easier this is to read, not to mention it is both shorter *and* working.

I also recommend to always use variable names in English. If you ever need to ask someone for help, for example here on Stack Overflow, it is much easier for them to understand your code if you use variable names that are easy to understand. This is also the reason why you should use the standardized names for Notes objects/classes.

I wrote a series of articles about how to write better Lotusscript code, I think they may help you: http://blog.texasswede.com/how-to-write-better-code-in-notesdomino/